# Filtered Crossfilter dimension vs defining dimension by filtered property

Tags: javascript, crossfilter

[Cook's Crossfilter tutorial](http://animateddata.co.uk/articles/crossfilter/) seems to accomplish a result in two different ways;

First defining a dimension by a general property, after which we apply a filter.

```
var delayDimension = cf.dimension(function(d) {return d.delay;});
delayDimension.filter(function(d) {return d > 0});
```

Directly obtaining the resulting dimension by defining the dimension by the property `d.delay > 0`:

```
var isDelayedDimension = cf.dimension(function(d) {return d.delay > 0;});
```

I'm wondering what the differences are between the two methods, with respect to performance.

Is there a difference in performance between directly defining a dimension by a specific property and defining the dimension in a more general way, after which we apply a specific filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These examples serve two different purposes.

The dimension in the first example allows you to group and filter by the amount of delay.

Then the filter *command* updates the dimension's filter so that, across the entire crossfilter instance, only flights with some delay are used when rows or aggregations are returned. The filter command is imperative: it doesn't create a new dimension which is filtered or return the filtered rows, just changes the filter property for that dimension and returns the same dimension.

The second example allows you to group and filter by the boolean "is it delayed or not". It does not yet perform any filtering. To get the equivalent effect as the filter command in the first example, you would do

```
isDelayedDimension.filter(true);
```

Again, this returns the same dimension, not a new one. It imperatively filters the data across the crossfilter instance so that other dimensions and groups based on them will no longer see any flights which are not delayed.

If this is all you want to do, filter by whether flights were delayed or not, then I think the second approach should be slightly faster, but it might not be a noticeable difference. It doesn't change the complexity of the algorithm but it may make the sorting a little easier if there are boolean values instead of integer values.

If for some reason you wanted to display aggregated or sorted flight delay information and also to filter based on whether flights are delayed, that would be one reason to use the first form: it can do both of these things and you could avoid creating a second dimension. Dimensions are the most expensive crossfilter objects.

However, [a group does not observe its own dimension's filters](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/Crossfilter-Gotchas#a-group-does-not-observe-its-dimensions-filters), so if you wanted the aggregated delay information to change when you filtered by "is delayed", you'd still need to use two dimensions.

Comment: *Again, this returns the same dimension, not a new one.* The practical difference between the two is the flexibility of one's ability to group the dimension, right? The motivation of my question arises from my desire to use a minimal amount of dimensions; and making more use of derived dimension to exploit the caching that's done on each "base dimension". If this sounds vague, please let me know; I don't have prior experience with Crossfilter. :)

Comment: Okay, I've added a little more info above to address these questions. However, this is starting to turn into a general discussion, and SO works better for focused questions (esp with specific code involved). I'd recommend taking this to the [dc.js users group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/dc-js-user-group) or the [crossfilter users group](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!forum/crossfilter) if you want to discuss further. But I'll take a look at your other question now.